# how to use ports inside alpine linux docker

Tags: docker, redis, alpine-linux

is there any way i can use redis service for my nodejs, i'am using alpine docker and somehow my node-redis client is not able to connect to redis (it says "**can not connect to 127.0.0.1:6479**"), i've tried many thing but it is not working,
and i want to achieve by only docker file not docker-compose.
here is my docker file code

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --update nodejs npm redis
EXPOSE 6379 9000
WORKDIR /server
COPY . /server/
RUN npm install
RUN redis-server &
CMD npm start
```

Comment: You should put it on the CMD line, or use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently to start multiple commands

Comment: A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process.  A standard setup here would be to run Redis in a separate container; if you want to avoid Compose for whatever reason, make sure to remember to create a network the two containers can use.  The other container will _not_ be 127.0.0.1 and you'll need to configure your application with its location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is `RUN redis-server &`. RUN statements are run at build time, so when your container starts up, the redis-server process isn't there anymore. You need to start it at run-time on the CMD statement like this

```
CMD redis-server & npm start
```

But as Zac points out, the 'docker way' to do it is to run Redis is a separate container. There are ready made redis images on docker hub you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* run multiple commands in one Docker container, but that's a bad practice. You could do this by having your `npm start` run a script that runs both your server and Redis, or using a package like `concurrently` or `npm-run-all`. Docker good practice is to have one executable per container, though, so the Docker-correct thing to do would be to put Redis in a separate container.